# ffmpeg in:h264 out:yuv to stdout - data format?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am (like many) trying to get a continuous series of still images out of the camera attached to a raspberry pi. I want to do this in java for all the usual reasons, and am using a Runtime exec command to pipe the output of raspivid to the following ffmpeg command, and then collecting the result via stdout --- note xxx.h264 is a test file generated by the camera that does not play because there is no container, but I am getting images out so half good.

```
ffmpeg -i xxx.h264 -vcodec rawvideo -r 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f nut -
```

I have some code displaying the frames, but they "march" across the display area from left to right, and there appears to be a growing amount of rubbish across the top of the images. I have looked at the bytes it outputs by running the same command and redirecting it into a file, then using vi/xxd and find that there is headder material ("nut/multimedia container ...").

I am guessing that there is more metadata inserted by my ffmpeg command, that I am failing to remove when processing the raw yuv420p data as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420sp_%28NV21%29_to_RGB_conversion_%28Android%29

For the life of me I cannot find the nut documentation anywhere in a readable format and anyway, it seems that is not what I should be looking for.  Any pointers as to how I can recognise the frame boundaries in my byte stream?

Answer (score 0):

`-f nut` represents the NUT container. Looks like you don't want any encapsulation, so use `-f rawvideo`. Also, the wiki link code is for `nv21`, which is a different layout for 4:2:0 data. `yuv420p` is all Y samples followed by all U samples, followed by all V samples. The U/V are half-width and half-height. If Y width or height is odd, the corresponding U/V dimension is int(Y/2) + 1

Comment: Yes that works. The NUT container does indeed add sync_points being "NKxxxxEi" at the start and after each frame.